# How do I see intermediate results in a recursive scala worksheet (IntelliJ)?

Tags: scala, debugging, recursion, intellij-idea

I am trying to understand specifically what happens when I change this line of code from:

`else f(a) * product(f)(a + 1, b)`

to:

`else f(a) * product(x => x)(a + 1, b)`

or:

`else f(a) * product(x => x * x)(a + 1, b)`

This is the complete code block:

```
object exercise {
  class Prod (){
    var acc: Int = 0

    def product(f: Int => Int)(a: Int, b: Int): Int = {

      acc = {
        if (a > b) 1
        else f(a) * product(f)(a + 1, b)
      }

      println(s"a: $a; b: $b; acc: $acc")
      acc
    }
  }

  val x = new Prod()

  x.product(x => x * x)(1, 5);
}
```

I'm using a scala worksheet in IntelliJ community edition 2016.2.4, if that matters.  I get different results each time I change`product(???)(a + 1, b)`. When I try to view just the output of the recursive function call, I get `java.lang.StackOverflowError`.  As the code is written, I see:

```
a: 5; b: 4; acc: 1
a: 4; b: 4; acc: 16
a: 3; b: 4; acc: 144
a: 2; b: 4; acc: 576
res2: Int = 576
```

How can I view the output of just that statement for each recursive iteration without causing an error?

Comment: but there isn't any error in *this* output, right? can you elaborate your issue?

Comment: also `x.product(x => x * x)(1, 5)` should be changed to `x.product(x => x * x)(1, 4)`

Comment: I apologize for the late reply.  I want to inspect just the intermediate results of `product(f)(a + 1, b)`, and not the whole definition of acc as it is written above.  Is this even possible?